# Cloning from github option is missing in android studio 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio

How to clone a repo from github in andoid studio

Here I'm attaching a screen shot
[image: Thers is only git and other options]

Comment: First, you have to choose git and then choose Log in to GitHub on the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the screenshot below
[image]
Paste/Enter the Git Repository Url and select the path where you want to Clone Repository.
[image]

After click on Clone , Then it will ask for GitHub credential if you not logged in.

Once Clone successfully then it will ask you to open the project and then you are ready.